# Access: Do you actually need to use subforms?

Tags: forms, ms-access, subform

So I have what is potentially a dumb question regarding MS Access. If I wish to make a form which can be used to populate multiple tables in a relational database, must these other tables be represented by subforms? From what I understand, you could manually change the RecordSource of the main form to include the rare one-to-one relationship, but is there any way such a thing would work for a one-to-many or a many-to-many relationship?

On its face, it seems to me that there's no way this would be possible-- after all, how would Access know how to arrange the multiple elements in a one-to-many relationship on the page?

I'm 90% sure the answer to this is "No, you must use subforms when designing a form which represents a relational model, unless it only contained one-to-one relationships", but I still feel I would be remiss if I didn't double-check this, since I basically jumped headfirst into Access development with no prior experience, and I want to make sure I'm not making an obvious mistake.

Comment: Yes, if there are multiple dependent tables, MUST use subforms. However, even if there were only 1 dependent table, advise use subform. Enforce relational integrity so don't get orphan records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, of course you don't *need* subforms. You can write all the code to manage loading related records, updating and deleting them, switching records, filtering, etc. yourself.

It's just that subforms are an incredibly convenient tool, ready for you to use.

And if you have to ask the question, you should probably use subforms and not try and re-invent the wheel.

<sub>I actually have written code to have about ~100 related records in a single form without using subforms while supporting read and update, because it met a specific goal, but I wouldn't recommend it to anyone</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can edit reocrds that are the result of a join to a main table, and a child table.

A few things are required for this to work.
You have to use a left join to the child table (else the query will not return any records.)

As long as the FK column of the child table, and the PK column of the parent table are included in the query, then this can work.

So say we have this setup in relationships.

[image]

Note VERY close how it is a left join. This allows (and means) that parent records can exist, and not child ones.

Now build a query like this:

[image]

Note how the first columns are from the main table, and the next 3 are from the child table.

So, when you open the query, assuming no child records, then you get this:

[image]

Note how the child reocrd(s) don't exist. If I type or enter data into the child table columns (say invoice number), move off to save, then you get this:

[image]

So in the above case, the data engine DOES know what FK value to set because you are on one main record. Of course, what you un-able to do here is add multiple child records, since you can't select or re-enter the main record again. However, if you separate added (say with a sub form) several child records, then you get this:

[image]

Once again, I can edit each row, and I can even edit the child columns.

And of course since this is a left join, then the main record is repeated each time for each child record.

And you CAN bind this query and use it for a form.

So such a setup is not much of use because you can't add new child records to a parent record, but you can certainly edit such data this way. And it DOES let you add "one" record, or "edit" the one child record. So, if the child record does not exist, then it will be added. And if the child record exists, then once again you can edit values in that child record. But, you can't add more then one child record with this UI.

So, while editing is possible, it not much of a usable UI.